# unisharp laravel file manager without php artisan serve

Tags: laravel, file-manager

i wont start my laravel 5.2 application without php artisan serve

when index.php are in public folder its work correctly
[IMAGE From Public Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBtgp.jpg)

and when  index.php are in root folder its stopping work
[Image From Root Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LITdF.jpg)

Comment: https://s23.postimg.org/t5o3ymrfv/code.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To include your css, js and asset you have to use asset() of laravel.

For Example your file is inside public/asset/css/custom.css

```
<link href="{!! asset('asset/css/custom.css') !!}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

it's also works when replace your public folder from public to public_html in server.

Comment: i use asset but in my view no include scripts 
this problem only in file manager. scripts include in plugin source  i dont wont change plugin scripts               https://s23.postimg.org/t5o3ymrfv/code.jpg

Comment: what is port number when you run your app. Normally to run Laravel you have to go in root folder and run command "php artisan serve --port=8000" you doing like this ?

Comment: That rising because Laravel Framework use public/index.php as first execution file. And you execute it from root.